# Pandas: merge dataframes based on occurrence value in a list

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes, which I try to merge.

The first one is the information about frequency of some entity (for example, keyword)

```
 keyword            freq
 specific code      3
 algorithm          2
 problem            1
 app                1
```

And the second dataframe with all the texts and their info

```
text_id   keywords                          text
1         ['specific code', 'algorithm']    We're here to help you with specific coding, algorithm.
2         ['algorithm', 'problem']          You can use this algorithm to solve your problem.
3         ['specific code']                 This specific code will help you.
4         ['specific code', 'app']          How to build a specific code for an app?
```

I want to merge them and get output dataframe

```
keyword         freq   text_id    text
specific code   3      1          We're here to help you with specific coding, algorithm.
specific code   3      3          This specific code will help you.
specific code   3      4          How to build a specific code for an app?
algorithm       2      1          We're here to help you with specific coding, algorithm.
algorithm       2      2          You can use this algorithm to solve your problem.
problem         1      2          You can use this algorithm to solve your problem.
app             1      4          How to build a specific code for an app?
```

I have right now code but it's not elegant at all

```
keywords = []
freq_keywords = []
ids = []
texts = []

for kw, kw_freq in zip(df_1[kw].values, df_1['freq'].values):
    for _, row in df_2.iterrows():
        if kw in row['keywords']:
            keywords.append(kw)
            freq_keywords.append(kw_freq)
            ids.append(row['text_id'])
            texts.append(row['text'])

output_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'keyword': keywords,
    'freq': freq_keywords,
    'text_id': ids,
    'text': texts,
})
```

So is it possible to it more elegant?
I think about using merge based on occurrence of value in the column `keyword` from the first dataframe `df_1` in the column `keywords` from the second dataframe `df_2`, but I didn't find something for that.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this should get you the results you are expecting

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'text_id' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'keywords' : [['specific code', 'algorithm'], ['algorithm', 'problem'], ['specific code'], ['specific code', 'app']],
    'Text' : ["We're here to help you with specific coding, algorithm.", 'You can use this algorithm to solve your problem.', 'This specific code will help you.', 'How to build a specific code for an app?']
})

df_merge = pd.merge(df1.explode('keywords'), df, left_on = 'keywords', right_on = 'keyword')
df_merge = df_merge[['keyword', 'freq', 'text_id', 'Text']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use `merge` after exploding the `keywords` column of the first DataFrame

```
out = (
    df_1.explode('keywords')
        .rename(columns={'keywords': 'keyword'})
        .merge(df_2, on='keyword')
)

print(out)
```

Output:

|  | text_id | keyword | text | freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | specific code | We're here to help you with specific coding, algorithm. | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | specific code | This specific code will help you. | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | specific code | How to build a specific code for an app? | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | algorithm | We're here to help you with specific coding, algorithm. | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | algorithm | You can use this algorithm to solve your problem. | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | problem | You can use this algorithm to solve your problem. | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | app | How to build a specific code for an app? | 1 |